# Other data sources in Alchemy News API

Tags: alchemyapi

Is it possible to feed other news sources than those given, into the Alchemy News API?

Answer (score 0):

News is a shared collection of content and we can't add customer sources. However, you can ingest custom sources in Watson Discovery service.

Alternatively, you can check if a source is included in AlchemyData News service with this query, where *YOUR_API_KEY* is your AlchemyAPI key and *wikipedia* is the domain of the source you want to check (omitting any subdomains, top-level domain names, or second-level domain names):

```
http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY&outputMode=json&start=now-30d&end=now&timeSlice=1d&q.enriched.url.url=wikipedia
```

[AlchemyData News API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemydata-news/api/v1/)